# Working with parentheses (English vs Japanese)

Tags: orthography, punctuation

In English I could write, "Birds (various kinds)".  In Japanese could I translate the version using parentheses as something like 鳥類（各種）, or should the language/parentheses be used differently?

I'm not sure what the rules are for round vs square parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have it is fine. In general, always use round parentheses, square parentheses are not used very much perhaps except only in specialized areas. However, it *is* common in Japan to use different types of parentheses when nesting, i.e. [()]. This is also why they are referred to as 小カッコ (), 中カッコ {} and 大カッコ [].

Comment: Don't forget these bad boys:【】〈〉〘〙《》 and so on

Comment: @ssb: As far as Japanese grammer is concerned, those versions have no valid use cases.

Comment: @JesseGood, can you elaborate? Who decides what is valid or not?

Comment: @dainichi: AFAIK, the [国語審議会](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/sanko/index.html) is originally responsible for deciding much of the punctuation use in Japan, and they only talk about (), 「」 and 『』. There are also many other "standards", one example is from [JIS](http://sti.jst.go.jp/sist/handbook/sist08/sist08_s.htm) for technical documents: `括弧は，丸括弧“（　）”及び角括弧“[　]”とし，補足，注解などに用い，その使い分けは，次による。`, as you can see they only talk about () and []. You may find use cases at publication companies that make their own in-house rules though.

Comment: @JesseGood, In くぎり符号の使ひ方, linked to from 国語審議会, it says "なほ各種のカッコを適当に用ひる。 (()) 〔〕 [] 【】", "use various parentheses as needed". I don't see how this supports your point that they are not valid.

Comment: @dainichi: I did not say "not valid", I said "no valid use cases". I did not mean you cannot use them, just that they have no specific functions in Japanese grammar.